# ActionListener code explanation needed

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jbutton, actionlistener

```
blueButton.addActionListener(new blueButtonListner());
```

What happens when this code is entered?

What I think is Java compiler creates an object called `blueButtonListner()` and it becomes an input to (parameters for) `addActionListener`

If that is correct as I guessed then this code should  also work:

```
redButton.addActionListener(rr);
redButtonListener rr =new redButtonListener();
```

But it shows an error.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: *"but it shows me an error"* Copy/paste the error.  They are intended to be self explanatory.

Comment: Mostly nullpointerexception since rr is null at that point(call to addActionListener)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Won't compile because `rr` is undefined in the first place

Comment: @ArunPJohny That's most likely NOT the case, because rr is not defined yet.

Comment: @RAY, yes I think you are right, then it is a compilation error. I was thinking it as a runtime exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter if precedence, you can't have something until it's created

```
redButton.addActionListener(rr); redButtonListener rr =new redButtonListener();
```

Won't work, because `rr` hasn't been defined yet, the compiler has not idea of what it is.

In contrast

```
blueButton.addActionListener(new blueButtonListner())
```

The compiler creates a temporary Object and passes it to the `addActionListener` method.

You can correct your code with this

```
redButtonListener rr =new redButtonListener();
redButton.addActionListener(rr);
```

Answer (score 6):

The listener object needs to be declared **before** it's used:

```
redButtonListener rr = new redButtonListener();
redButton.addActionListener(rr);
```

You're correct about `blueButton.addActionListener(new blueButtonListner());`. This statement creates an *instance* of the class`blueButtonListener` which is immediately passed to `addActionListener`.

Comment: This is incorrect. No anonymous inner class is created in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code the other way around:

```
redButtonListener rr =new redButtonListener();

redButton.addActionListener(rr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The listener needs to be created first before it can be added. Try the following:

```
redButtonListener rr =new redButtonListener();
redButton.addActionListener(rr);
```

Note we you get an error, usually reading carefully what the error says should give me the answer you need. In this case, it should tell you that rr is not defined, which is clearly because by the time you use it, it doesn't exist yet.